# Почему не применяются изменения в python скрипте?

Tags: python

У меня есть python скрипт скачанный с github, он отлично работает. Я хочу в нем изменить текстовую информацию которая выводится в консоль `print('text...')`

я изменяю текст на нужный мне, но в консоль все равно печатает старый текст.

изначально я подумал что редактирую не тот файл, но выполнив поиск текста по всему проекту - текст который мне нужно отредактировать находиться только в одном файле, и я его редактирую и точно сохраняю.

такое впечатление что нужно как-то обновить что-то...

буду благодарен за помощь!

python 3.10, скрипт который запускаю [GHunt](https://github.com/mxrch/GHunt), строку которую редактирую https://github.com/mxrch/GHunt/blob/master/ghunt/modules/email.py#L50

Comment: Нужно больше подробностей. Какая версия питона, какая версия ОС, какой скрипт, как скачали, как и куда установили, как запустили и не забыли ли перезапустить после внесения изменений?

Comment: @andreymal добавил в вопрос

Comment: @andreymal скачал через команду `git clone` , установил `python3 setup.py install` , внес изменения и запускаю так `ghunt email test@gmail.com`

Comment: setup.py install сделал **копию** всех файлов в ваше текущее python-окружение, а значит нужно или не забыть изменить эту самую копию тоже, или выполнить install повторно

Comment: Вы локально меняете строку и запускаете локально? Или меняете в гите а запускаете локально или наоборот?

Comment: @andreymal заметил изменения когда повторно выполнил `setup.py install`. но не удобно же после каждого изменения так делать. как этого избежать?

Comment: Вместо install использовать develop например